# How to turn a url segment into a single parameter in Play! Framework

Tags: java, json, routes, playframework, same-origin-policy

**Problem**

I want url segment`here/is/a/request/to/letsay/a/user` to turn into one single parameter `orginalRequest` in Play! route

**Why**

To solve Same Origin Policy with JSON and AJAX, we have decided to have a [web services client](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/libs#WebServiceclient) running on our own server that redirect all JSON call to an external REST API.

Is there a way in the Play! Framework route file that I can threat what ever comes after /api/ as one single parameter?

In route:

```
GET    /api/fromhere/is/what/iwant/as/single/parameter    App.getFromOtherDomain
```

In App:

```
public void getFromOtherDomain(String orginalRequest){    
   WSRequest req = WS.url("https://api.otherdomain.com/" + orginalRequest);
   Promise<HttpResponse> respAsync = req.getAsync();
   HttpResponse resp = await(respAsync);   
   renderJSON(resp.getJson());
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **Play 1.x** you use a RegEx:

Routes:

```
 GET   /files/{<[a-z0-9/\.]*>name}               Application.download(name)
```

In **Play 2.0** you can do it a bit shorter:

Routes:

```
GET   /files/*name                               Application.download(name)
```

Call:

```
http://yourserver/files/public/downloads/hello.png
```

In the download action, `name` will equal `"public/downloads/hello.png"`.

Comment: thanks, nice that this will work in 2.0, but I am still working on version 1.2.3

Answer (score 1):

From your controller you can use the [request.path and request.uri](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.3/play/mvc/Http.Request.html) to extract the info you need and then call your other method with the info extracted.

Comment: But how do you do it in the route folder? How do you get all calls to /api/../../../ to go to Application.api()?